# Limitations using Salesforce with Apex Class Connector? How should I architect an external database connector

Tags: apex, rest-api, externalobjects, salesforce-connect

Our external database has 3 million records. I want to leverage Salesforce Connect to bring the external data into Salesforce without copying it into Salesforce.

I am getting my Data from the [Metabase API](https://www.metabase.com/learn/administration/metabase-api) and the table that we are querying `SELECT * from Organization_Transactions` has around 3 Million rows of data and its obviously growing.

I am [watching a video online from Salesforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBwnE2S3T6o) that shows the creation of connecting any external data source with a custom apex connector but I am not sure if it would be able to handle processing 3 million rows of data.

Salesforce has posted their [limits online here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.platform_connect_general_limits.htm&type=5) but their is no mention of heap limits, timeout limits, etc for handling large data volumes.

At the end of the day, Salesforce connect is built to handle external database with large amounts of data. It should be able to consume large data volumes quite easily. I am just unsure if APEX is able to handle this. Maybe the best approach here is to use batch apex?

Comment: _I want to leverage Salesforce Connect to bring the external data into Salesforce without copying it into Salesforce_ - [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @identigral Why is this an xy problem? I am asking if Salesforce connect can handle LDV using Apex connector.

Comment: This is your proposed solution. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @identigral I an trying to see if the Apex Class connector can handle 3 million rows of data being returned in JSON format. Is this the correct architecture?

Comment: How are you planning on using this data?

Comment: @identigral We plan on reporting on Monthly customer spending data. We want to see the trends over time and what product categories they are spending on for the account management team.

Comment: Reporting on 3M records that will be "joined" to whatever is in SF and then filtered/rolled-up/etc is _not_ the use case for data virtualization.

Comment: @identigral so then for what I am looking for, what would recommend? Is the idea that everything should have a filter? So if I want to virtualize the data it has to meet specific criteria?

Comment: You want to copy the data. Look at the architecture of SF Genie or any modern data-rich solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have normal limits for connectors. In other words, no, you won't be querying 3,000,000+ rows in a single transaction. Instead, you'll have to look at the [QueryContext](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_DataSource_QueryContext.htm)#get parameters `offset` and `maxRecords`, and include those parameters to your callout. It's only through pagination that you can access all 3,000,000+ records in realtime.

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample of what this would look like. I am researching online as well and am struggling to find a working example for sending a request using query context offest and maxrecods.